# replace the following text with "" at the end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a variable that gets appended to a string early, but I need to replace it with an empty string if a condition is met (that condition can only be determined later on in the code).

For example:

```
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\">\n";
```

I now need to replace what gets appended to the `$output` string here with an empty string.  This gets done elsewhere, but I still have access to the $indent variable, so I know how many "\t" has been added.

So, I know I can do it using `preg_match` and `preg_replace` like so:

```
if (preg_match("/\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\">\n$/", $output))
    $output = preg_replace("/\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\">\n$/", "", $output);
else
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
```

But I am wondering on the performance here, and if there is a better way to do this?  If someone can provide an example using my exact `$output` with newline and tab characters, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact string, and you only want to remove it from the end of `$output`, using a regular expressions is really inefficient because it scans the whole string and parses it for regex rules.

Suppose we call the text you wish to crop `$suffix`. I would do:

```
//find length of whole output and of just the suffix
$suffix_len = strlen($suffix);
$output_len = strlen($output);

//Look at the substring at the end of ouput; compare it to suffix
if(substr($output,$output_len-$suffix_len) === $suffix){
    $output = substr($output,0,$output_len-$suffix_len); //crop
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/22JTs)

Comment: That looks good and all, but how is `strlen` output effected when using `/n`, `/t`, and/or `/r`?

Comment: For the Record `echo strlen("\n\n");` is 2, while `echo strlen('\n\n');` is 4.  There is a difference, but in any case, seems to be working with the newlines and tabs.  Thanks again!